# Scripting.Dictionary keys to Listbox VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, scripting.dictionary

I have been working with VBA in excel and recently began working with the Scripting.Dictionary object. I hadn't run across any major problems until today.

Basically I am trying to populate a listbox with the Key values of a dictionary, then add one more value to the listbox. This results in the value not only being added to the listbox, but also to the dictionary as a key. I have attempted to copy the values from the dict.keys() array to a completely separate array, but still have the same issue. I assume this is a byref problem but have yet to figure out a solution. If anyone has any ideas that would be awesome.

```
Private Sub Setup_settingLst()
'Set Settings listbox items
    'On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Dim list_ary() As Variant
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    settingLst.Clear
    settingLst.Value = "-Select Setting-"
    i = 0
    tmp = tmp_dict.Keys()
    If tmp_dict.Count > 1 Then
        ReDim list_ary(0 To tmp_dict.Count)
        For i = 0 To UBound(tmp)
            list_ary(i) = tmp(i)
        Next i
        list_ary(tmp_dict.Count) = "Back"
    Else
        ReDim list_ary(0 To tmp_dict.Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(tmp)
            list_ary(i) = tmp(i)
        Next i
    End If
    settingLst.List = list_ary
    Erase list_ary
    Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried to recreate your issue, but the code seems to work OK for me. Please post the rest of your code, including how `tmp_Dict` is declared and populated, and how `Setup_settingLst` is called, as this may affect the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    Dim dcValues As Scripting.Dictionary

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Set dcValues = FillDictionary

    Me.ListBox1.List = dcValues.Keys
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "Back"

End Sub
```